# Restore Tiles view in Promoted Links

Tags: 2013, promoted-links

An user of our Sharepoint site made a mistake and has - as it appears to be - deleted the Tiles view from the Promoted Links app. The promoted links for that particular widget are now shown like a general Sharepoint list instead of the tiles.

When I look in "Change view" I can only find the "All Promoted Links" view. I tried to restore the tiles view from the recycle bin but it still shows as a regular list.

If I recreate the view from Sharepoint Designer I get:

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'indexOf' of undefined or null reference
>
> TypeError: Unable to get property 'indexOf' of undefined or null reference

Is it possible to fix the list without needing to recreate it? I have Sharepoint Designer access if needed.

Comment: You can create a Tiles view with the help of SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 1):

As you are now recieving an error

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'indexOf' of undefined or null reference.

I assume a part of the generated list view was trying to reference your original tiled view.

I would try (I haven't tested this) to create a new view by copying across a working tiled view from another list. Firstly you will need to have/ create another promoted links list within the site. Each view is an aspx page, so in sharepoint designer you can navigate to lists, select the working promoted links list and under views you should see "Tiles". Click on it to open the aspx source in SPD.

Select All and copy it into a text editor of your choice (I recommend notepad++)

Next you're going to open up your broken list, and if you have a view called "Tiles", open it, or create one. Now there are a couple things within this "Tiles" view that are important, primarily the List ID and the View ID, but also the URL. You should be able to search for either and find results that look similar to `ListName="{AA-22-AA-22-A2A2A2}" ListId="aa-22-aa-22-a2a2a2"` & `ViewGuid="{XX-00-XX-00-X0X0X0}" View Name="{XX-00-XX-00-X0X0X0}"`

Once you have those items, go back to the source you saved in the text file. You will need to edit the line ~21:

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" ViewFlag="" ViewSelectorFetchAsync="False" InplaceSearchEnabled="True" ServerRender="False" ClientRender="True" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" IsClientRender="False" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" NoDefaultStyle="" ViewGuid="{XX-00-XX-00-X0X0X0}" EnableOriginalValue="False" DisplayName="Tiles" ViewContentTypeId="" Default="TRUE" ListUrl="" ListDisplayName="" ListName="{A25F535D-D2B3-4975-8B1F-680DC9DE3DAE}" ListId="a25f535d-d2b3-4975-8b1f-680dc9de3dae" PageType="PAGE_DEFAULTVIEW" PageSize="-1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" DataSourceID="" ShowWithSampleData="False" AsyncRefresh="False" ManualRefresh="False" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" Title="Projects Navigator" FrameType="Default" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="" IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="Main" PartOrder="2" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" TitleUrl="/sites/collection/Lists/ListName" DetailLink="/sites/collection/Lists/ListName" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="False" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_xx_00_xx_00_x0x0x0" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{XX-00-XX-00-X0X0X0}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" __designer:CustomXsl="Fldtypes_mswhTitle.xsl;fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><ParameterBindings>
```

For the values

```
TitleUrl="/sites/collection/Lists/ListName"
DetailLink="/sites/collection/Lists/ListName"
ViewGuid="{XX-00-XX-00-X0X0X0}"
View Name="{XX-00-XX-00-X0X0X0}"
ListName="{AA-22-AA-22-A2A2A2}"
ListId="aa-22-aa-22-a2a2a2"
ID="g_xx_00_xx_00_x0x0x0"
__WebPartId="{XX-00-XX-00-X0X0X0}"
```

and also ~line 33

```
<View Name="{XX-00-XX-00-X0X0X0}" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" Type="HTML" ReadOnly="TRUE" OrderedView="TRUE" DisplayName="Tiles" Url="/sites/collection/Lists/ListName/Tiles.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" >
```

For the values

```
View Name="{XX-00-XX-00-X0X0X0}"
Url="/sites/collection/Lists/ListName/Tiles.aspx"
```

Once you have replaced all the values in the saved text file with the values from your broken list view, you can copy all the text and paste it over the source for the broken view within SharePoint Designer. Save it and your view should work now.

Answer (score 0):

In Sharepoint Designer the 'create new view' for promoted links web parts should create the tiles view by default

Comment: That does work, but partially. I have updated my question.